# I want to record a sound in android phone for 6 seconds with sampling rate of 8000hz in .wav

Tags: java, android, audio, mediarecorder

```
if(checkSelfPermissionFromDevice() )
    {
        btnRecord.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                pathSave= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        .getAbsolutePath()+"/"
                        + UUID.randomUUID().toString()+"_audio_record.wav";
                mediaRecorder.setAudioChannels(1);
                mediaRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(8000);
                mediaRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(44100);
                setupMediaRecorder();

                try
                {
                    mediaRecorder.prepare();
                    mediaRecorder.start();
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
                btnPlay.setEnabled(false);
                btnStop.setEnabled(false);

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Recording...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //add delay of 6 seconds+then stop recording

                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Stopped Recording", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                //then enable  play button()
                btnPlay.setEnabled(true);
                btnStop.setEnabled(false);
```

**I want to add 6 seconds delay so that I can stop recording after that or only to record for 6 seconds using builtin function by passing parameters please guide...**

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `android.os.Handler` to run a some code with 6 seconds delay using the `postDelayed` function. [Handler Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long))

Example code:

```java
Handler h = new Handler();
h.postDelayed(() -> {
    // stop the recording here
}, 6 * 1000);
```

A crucial point is, that you shouldn't pause the main thread for 6 seconds with something like `Thread.sleep()` because then the user experience would suffer and the android system will show a dialog that the app is unresponsive. Therefore you should schedule the stopping time (i.e. with a Handler) and let the main thread run in the mean time, such that the UI is updated and responsive.

Comment: Can I save my output file in .WAV? like         mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.WAV);
MediaRecorder doesn't support  .wav I guess

Comment: I'd guess that wav is not supported as it is not mentioned in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.OutputFormat) but I am by no means an expert in this domain.

Comment: is there any way like we use library to convert on the runtime to .wav?